# What does String do that I'm not doing? c++11

Tags: c++11, stdstring

I am still new to c++, so bear with me.

I was trying to learn more about how std::move works and I saw an example where they used std::move to move the string to a different function and then showed using std::cout that no string remained. I thought cool, let's see if I can make my own class and do the same:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class integer
{
private:
    int *m_i;
public:
    integer(int i=0) : m_i(new int{i})
    {
        std::cout << "Calling Constructor\n";
    }

    ~integer()
    {
        if(m_i != nullptr) {
            std::cout << "Deleting integer\n";
            delete m_i;
            m_i = nullptr;
        }
    }

    integer(integer&& i) : m_i(nullptr)  // move constructor
    {
        std::cout << "Move Constructor\n";
        m_i = i.m_i;
        i.m_i = nullptr;
    }
    integer(const integer& i) : m_i(new int) {  // copy constructor
        std::cout << "Copy Constructor\n";
        *m_i = *(i.m_i);
    }
//*
    integer& operator=(integer&& i) {   // move assignment
        std::cout << "Move Assignment\n";
        if(&i != this) {
            delete m_i;
            m_i = i.m_i;
            i.m_i = nullptr;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    integer& operator=(const integer &i) {   // copy assignment
        std::cout << "Copy Assignment\n";
        if(&i != this) {
           m_i = new int;
           *m_i = *(i.m_i);
        }
       return *this;
    }
    int& operator*() const { return *m_i; }
    int* operator->() const { return m_i; }

    bool empty() const noexcept {
       if(m_i == nullptr) return true;
       return false;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const integer i) {
       if(i.empty()) {
           std::cout << "During overload, i is empty\n";
           return out;
       }
    out << *(i.m_i);
    return out;
    }
};

void g(integer i) { std::cout << "G-wiz - "; std::cout << "The g value is " <<  i << '\n'; }
void g(std::string s) { std::cout << "The g value is " << s << '\n'; }

int main()
{
    std::string s("Hello");

    std::cout << "Now for string\n";
    g(std::move(s));
    if(s.empty()) std::cout << "s is empty\n";
    g(s);
    std::cout << "\nNow for integer\n";
    integer i = 77;
    if(!i.empty()) std::cout << "i is " << i << '\n';
    else std::cout << "i is empty\n";
    g(i);
    std::cout << "Move it\n";
    g(std::move(i));  // rvalue ref called
    if(!i.empty()) std::cout << "i is " << i << '\n';
    else std::cout << "i is empty\n";
    g(i);

    return 0;
}
```

And this is my output:

```
Now for string
The g value is Hello
s is empty
The g value is

Now for integer
Calling Constructor
Copy Constructor
i is 77
Deleting integer
Copy Constructor
G-wiz - Copy Constructor
The g value is 77
Deleting integer
Deleting integer
Move it
Move Constructor
G-wiz - Copy Constructor
The g value is 77
Deleting integer
Deleting integer
i is empty
Copy Constructor

Process returned 255 (0xFF)   execution time : 7.633 s
Press any key to continue.
```

As you can see, it crashes when it enters g the second time, never even getting to the operator<<() function. How is it that the empty std::string s can be passed to g where my empty integer i crashes the program?

Edit: Fixed new int vs. new int[] error. Thanks n.m.

Comment: A hand-rolled move constructor typically makes use of `std::move` to move members.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that solved the problem. Which if I understand it was that in the move constructor (and assignment operator) I was treating i.m_i as an lvalue rather than an rvalue. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "empty integer" crashes the program because it contains a null pointer. You are trying to dereference it when you use it at the right hand side of the assignment.

An empty string is a normal usable string. There are no unchecked null pointer dereferences in the `std::string` code.

You have to ensure that the empty state of your object is a usable one. Start with defining a default constructor. Does it make sense for your class? If not, then move semantic probably doesn't either. If yes, a moved-from object in the move constructor should probably end up in the same state as a default-constructed object. A move assignment can act as a swap operation, so there the right-hand-side may end up either empty or not.

If you don't want to define a usable empty state for your class, and still want move semantics, you simply cannot use an object after it has been moved from. You still need to make sure that an empty object is destructible.

Comment: The point of this exercise was not practical, but to learn how std::move worked. How does one make an empty object destructible?

Comment: The destructor shouldn't crash or have other undesirable behaviour. It depends on what the destructor does, but basically if there's a pointer you want to `delete`, the pointer must point to an object that can be `delete`d, or be a `nullptr`. You already have that in your class. Mind another bug, sometimes you call `new int` and sometimes `new int[1]`. This is illegal.

Comment: I fixed the "new int/new int[1]" problem (thanks, see above). I have determined that the program crashes prior to calling std::cout, so the act of calling g with an empty integer is somehow different than calling g with an empty std::string. I'm still missing something. Sorry to be so dense.

Comment: I have already explained it. Your empty integer has a null pointer. Your access functions dereference the pointer without checking. This is not allowed in C++. You need to decide whether an empty integer is a valid object for you. It is not clear what semantics an empty integer would have. How much is an empty integer plus 2? What does it meam to print an empty integer? You need to think it all through, write it down and implement it. An empty string is valid and has well defined seantics.